# im traying to install pymavlink 2.2.3 version with pip on windows how can I do it?

Tags: python, windows, pip, version, dronekit-python

im traying to install pymavlink 2.2.3 version with pip on windows how can I do it?? because i have a conflicts with the versions of mavproxy and dronekit any idea what I can do?

this says that I need pymavlink version 2.0.6 for dronekit 2.9.1 but i have pymavlink 2.2.20 and that is compatible with mavproxy other one dosent work

Answer (score 0):

`dronekit` 2.9.1 [requires](https://github.com/dronekit/dronekit-python/blob/3d6479a42ba8601ef9a5c771a85fa090336c9928/setup.py#L14) `pymavlink` 2.0.6. Install it with the command

```
pip install -U pymavlink==2.0.6
```

Or install all dependencies at once with

```
pip install -U dronekit
```

If you think the requirement is a bug report it at dronekit issue tracker.